# best way to deploy php applications from svn to dev or prod server on windows

Tags: php, apache, svn, deployment, web-deployment

I have [VisualSVN server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) where I have my codes. Does anybody know the best application out there that I can use to deploy my php applications to either a development or production server from SVN? I tried Fredistrano but that didn't work. I would prefer free licensing and very easy to use and set up software.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Have you tried jenkins?
http://jenkins-ci.org/